# Doctrine: RuntimeException - Not all identifier properties can be found in the ResultSetMapping

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I started using Doctrine and ran into trouble immediately. I have an entity defined as follows:

```
namespace AdminModule;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="admin_user")
 */
class User extends \Nette\Object
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="guid")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $registered;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $last_login;

}
```

If I call

```
$u = $this->em->getRepository('AdminModule\User')->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u.username, u.id')
            ->from('AdminModule\User', 'u');
```

I get the RuntimeException stating that identifier property "id" is missing. However, when I run the above code with getQuery() and execute() it, it returns the result I want.

Can you help me out? If more information is needed, just tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Please add the definition of your User entity

Comment: User entity definition added.

Comment: What is the code your execute after the `$u = $this->...` line?